# Can I display environment variables in IntellIJ without running a program to do so?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to display the environment variables in force when IntelliJ was loaded (e.g. that would be used by builds executed directly from the right sidebar). Is there a way to do this from the UI? The only way I know to do it currently is by running some code, such as the following Java fragment:

```
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
        }
```

Comment: does this help? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/add-environment-variables-and-program-arguments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate @Nikos M.'s suggestion:

[image]